# Register page in admin area

Tags: wp-admin, forms

Ok, so I have a table in my admin area for my plugin. Each row as an edit button, which should post to the edit page. I don't know how to add my php edit page to the registered wordpress page, though, so I don't know what to put for action in the form.

```
        <td><form action="[edit.php]" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $issue->id?>" name="id" value="1">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit">
            </form>
        </td>
```

So what should I put inside the brackets (and yes, I will remove the brackets), and where/how do I add edit.php so wordpress knows it exists?

UPDATE: So apparently I just add edit.php normally, but specify null for its parent. Stil no idea what to put in those brackets.

UPDATE 2: Apparently the function I was looking for was menu_page_url...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <td><form action="<?php menu_page_url('edit') ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $issue->id?>" name="id" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit">
        </form>
    </td>
```

Then, in the function where you add your admin pages:

```
    add_submenu_page( null, 'edit', 'Edit', $capability, 'edit', 'create_edit');
```

Also add this function:

```
function create_edit(){
    include 'edit.php';
}
```

It would probably be a good thing to have more unique names than these.